# Modulus for reduction in BLS Signature Scheme

Tags: modular-arithmetic, group-theory, bls-signature

I'm currently working with BLS Signature Schemes in the field of publicly verifiable [Compact Proofs of Retrievability](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/073.pdf) by Shacham and Waters.

So for creating the Sigmas the following function is defined:
$$
\sigma_i \leftarrow\left(H(\text { name } \| i) \cdot u^{m_{i}}\right)^\alpha .
$$
$\left\{m_{i}\right\}_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq n}}$ are bytes derived from a File $M$ which is devided into $n$ blocks. $u$ is a generator of $G_1$. $\alpha$ is the private key with $\alpha \stackrel{\mathrm{R}}{\leftarrow} \mathbb{Z}_p$. The hash function is defined as $H:\{0,1\}^* \rightarrow G_1$

The Proofs are generated by:
$$\mu \leftarrow \sum_{\left(i, \nu_i\right) \in Q} \nu_i m_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$$

and

$$\quad \sigma \leftarrow \prod_{\left(i, \nu_i\right) \in Q} \sigma_i^{\nu_i} \in G_1 $$

where $\nu_i \stackrel{\mathrm{R}}{\leftarrow} \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Finally the verification is done by the following pairing:
$$
e(\sigma, g_2) \stackrel{?}{=} e\left(\prod_{\left(i, \nu_i\right) \in Q} H(\text { name } \| i)^{\nu_i} \cdot u^{\mu}, v\right) ;
$$

Where $v$ is the public key computed by $v \leftarrow g^\alpha$ and $g_2$ is a generator of $G_2$

**The problem:**

As $\mu$ in the proof generation becomes a big number, my idea was to apply a modulus on $m_i$. I would choose a random prime $c \stackrel{\mathrm{R}}{\leftarrow} \mathbb{Z}_p$ and reduce $m_i$ in the sigma generation and the proof generation.

So the new construction of $\sigma_i$ and $\mu$ would look like this:

$$
\sigma_i \leftarrow\left(H(\text { name } \| i) \cdot u^{(m_{i} \bmod c)}\right)^\alpha .
$$

$$\mu \leftarrow \sum_{\left(i, \nu_i\right) \in Q} \nu_i \cdot (m_{i} \bmod c) \in \mathbb{Z}_p$$

**The question:**

Does applying the modulus like this lower the security of the  authenticators (sigmas) in a bad way?

**A solution:**
As @poncho pointed out, I can just apply  $\mu \bmod p$ where $p$ is the prime order of $G_1$ in order to bring the size of $\mu$ down and still have a valid pairing. So I do not need to fiddle around with the bytes I'm reading as i wrote in my idea.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: "my idea was to apply a modulus on $m_i$. I would choose a random prime..."; wouldn't the obvious idea be to reduce things modulo $p$ (the order of $G_1$)?

Comment: That would be obvious, but that does not reduce it enough. $p$ is of bit size 254 as I'm using alt_bn128 curves. When using modulo $p$ the order of $G_1$) $\mu$ results in 341 bit. But as i need to fit $\mu$ into a 32byte integer this is not suitable. So my thoughts where to choose a $p$ of 128 bit size for $c$ as this results in $\mu$ being 215 bits.

Comment: Huh?  If you reduce things modulo $p$, you should never get anything larger than $p$ - if $p$ is 254 bits, the value you get should always fit in 32 bytes.

Comment: But $\mu$ as described above is the sum of some amount of $m_i$, and building the sum can result in a number being bigger than 32 bytes. If you mean i could just apply modulo to $\mu$ itself, from my understanding this is not possible as it does break the pairing.

Comment: "from my understanding ... it does break the pairing" - no, why would it?  After all, the pairing works on groups of order $p$ - hence reducing things modulo $p$ doesn't change anything...

Comment: Would you be kind enough to give me the formulas where you think I should reduce for computing $\mu$ and $\sigma_i$? I tried to implement it as you suggested but the pairing does not work this way.

Comment: $\mu \leftarrow \sum_{\left(i, \nu_i\right) \in Q} \nu_i m_{i} \bmod p$

Comment: That is what i tried. I applied mod directly $\mu \bmod p$. And as expected it brings $\mu$ down to the expected bit size.  But the pairing breaks in this case. Do i have to apply the modulus to the other calculations of the pairing as well?

Comment: Okay nevermind I was just an idiot, i choose a random number of the size of $p$ instead of using the order directly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "my idea was to apply a modulus on $m_i$. I would choose a random prime...";

Wouldn't the obvious idea be to reduce things modulo $p$ (the order of $G_1$)?  After all, the pairing works on groups of order $p$ - hence reducing things modulo $p$ doesn't change anything..

[This added to give you an answer you can accept]